# How to make a prod and dev environment in a DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions, digital-ocean, cicd

Using Github action we deploy to a single Digital ocean Droplet a dev and prod dockerized Django/db containers.

We need to separate the dev and prod logic, and be able to deploy each of them separately.

Do I need to add a new droplet for dev?

Do I need to make a separate Github action, and docker-compose.yml for dev and prod?

Github action:

```yaml
name: Identifier Name
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main


jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:    
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: upload files
        uses: burnett01/rsync-deployments@5.2
        with:
          switches: --exclude=".git" --exclude=".github" --exclude=".env" --exclude="logs" -avzr --delete
          path: ./
          remote_path: /root/Name
          remote_host: ${{ secrets.ssh_ip }}
          remote_user: ${{ secrets.ssh_user }}
          remote_key: ${{ secrets.key }}


      - name: build & start project
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.ssh_ip }}
          username: ${{ secrets.ssh_user }}
          key: ${{ secrets.key }}
        env: 
          POSTGRES_USER: ${{ secrets.postgres_user }} 
          POSTGRES_DB: ${{ secrets.postgres_db }} 
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.postgres_password }} 
          POSTGRES_HOST: ${{ secrets.postgres_host }} 
          POSTGRES_PORT: ${{ secrets.postgres_port }} 
          POSTGRES_PROD_PORT: ${{ secrets.postgres_prod_port }} 
          POSTGRES_DEV_PORT: ${{ secrets.postgres_dev_port }} 
          POSTGRES_ENGINE: ${{ secrets.postgres_engine }} 
          script: |
            docker-compose -f /root/Name/docker-compose.yml build 
            && docker-compose -f /root/Name/docker-compose.yml down 
            && docker-compose -f /root/Name/docker-compose.yml up -d

      - name: run migrations prod
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.ssh_ip }}
          username: ${{ secrets.ssh_user }}
          key: ${{ secrets.key }}
          script: "docker exec -i prod python manage.py migrate"
          
      - name: run migrations dev
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.ssh_ip }}
          username: ${{ secrets.ssh_user }}
          key: ${{ secrets.key }}
          script: "docker exec -i dev python manage.py migrate"
```

Docker compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:1.22.0
    container_name: webserver
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
      - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro
      - ./nginx/configs/:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/:ro
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

  db_prod:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: db_prod
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PROD_PORT}:5432
    volumes:
      - db_prod:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    profiles:
      - prod

  db_dev:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: db_dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_DEV_PORT}:5432
    volumes:
      - db_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    profiles:
      - dev

  prod:
    build: ./src
    command: ["./start.sh"]
    container_name: prod
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5002:5000
    volumes:
      - env_prod:/env:delegated
      - .env:/app/.env:ro
      - ./logs/prod/gunicorn/:/var/log/gunicorn/
    depends_on:
      - db_prod
    environment:
      LOG_PATH: /var/log
      POSTGRES_HOST: db_prod
    profiles:
      - prod

  dev:
    build: ./src
    command: ["./start.sh"]
    container_name: dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    volumes:
      - env_dev:/env:delegated
      - .env:/app/.env:ro
      - ./logs/dev/gunicorn/:/var/log/gunicorn/
    depends_on:
      - db_dev
    environment:
      LOG_PATH: /var/log
      POSTGRES_HOST: db_dev
    profiles:
      - dev

  adminer:
    image: dockette/adminer:pgsql
    container_name: adminer
    restart: always
    environment:
      UPLOAD: ${ADM_UPLOAD}
    profiles:
      - dev
      - prod

volumes:
  db_prod:
  db_dev:
  env_dev:
  env_prod:
```

Comment: You could eventually use a reusable workflow (github action) which would perform the same operations for both environments, but with different inputs according the chosen environment. And have a generic Dockerfile which would be filled with env variables according to the context you're in for each workflow run.

Comment: Would this mean adding another droplet in Digitalocean? or one would handle both environment, with separate deployments for each?

Comment: You could go with both solutions (one or two droplets). But as you plan to separate the dev and prod logic, you could go with a different droplet for each as well (it would be like using different [self-hosted runners on github](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners), if it makes sense)